# Arrays and smart pointers

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

1.1) Is there a possibility of a memory leak when using std::vector, QVector, boost::array (not quite understand the difference between them in the use of memory and what are the advantages of each)? Or they follow the memory as smart pointers?

1.2) Or is it better to create them through a shared_ptr?

2) What better shared_aray or shared_ptr + vector?

Comment: please be more specific with your question. This is no thing that can be answered as general as you've asked for.

Comment: Downvoting and close-voting? This seems like a pretty OK question to me, especially for a first one. I've certainly seen much worse around here.

Comment: If anyone reads this belated comment, just did not know how best to combine smart pointers and vector vector <shared_ptr <T>> or ptr_vector <T> or shared_ptr <vector <T >>. It is clear that all of these options have a place to be, but there must be something more correct, more safer to use and without the potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility of memory leak in either of those three *in the memory they manage.* That is, the data stored in a `std::vector`, `QVector` or `std::array` will be correctly deallocated when the container is destroyed.

On the other hand, if you manage the container *itself* in an unsafe way, you can of course leak the entire container. E.g. if you do something like `new std::vector<int>()` and later leak the pointer which `new` gave you. Note that there is very rarely reason to allocate containers dynamically.

Also, if you store unsafe pointers in the containers, you can of course leak what such pointers point to.

As for the difference between the containers you listed:

- `std::vector` holds a contiguous array of memory, and it is capable of growing dynamically when it needs more space. Each such growth involves allocating larger space and moving the currently stored elements into the new space, then deallocating the old one.
- `QVector` is a weird beast, similar a bit to `std::deque`. Internally, it's implemented as if it was a vector of pointers. That is, you won't be too far off if you think of `QVector<T>` as equivalent to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, for `T` larger than a pointer, and `std::vector<T>` for `T` pointer-sized or smaller.
- `std::array` is fundamentally different from the above two in that it doesn't hold dynamic memory, and cannot grow dynamically. `std::array<T, N>` is just a very thin wrapper around `T [N]`, giving it a container-like interface.

Regarding your question 2, each is different again: a `shared_array` cannot grow once it's allocated, `std::vector` can. There is very rarely a reason to store `std::vector` in a smart pointer (or any pointer), since it's rare to allocate it dynamically in the first place.